# What is the meaning of "is held up to "

Tags: meaning-in-context

> This all raises the question as to whether it is appropriate to look
>   to athletic figures as role models and whether they should be held up
>   to circumspect levels of conduct.

According to the dictionary, *is held up* as a passive structure means; 'pay attention to, single out'. That may be true,but don't you think that in this sentence it doesn't work? What do you think would be the best equivalent?

Comment: It seems fine as it is to me. The meaning is clear, I don't think that the dictionary extract has given all the possible connotations and/or contexts. You could reword as "... whether we should expect them to behave in accordance with a formal code of conduct".

Comment: It looks like a once-off sense of the phrase, based on the sense noted in one of the answers ("expose", as when you hold a small object up to the light to examine it). It's used in your example to mean "compare", or "measure against."

Answer (score 1):

The phrasal verb **hold up** with the following senses makes the sentence in question clear and meaningful.

> **[hold up:](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/hold-up)** (Collins Dictionary)
>
> *5. If you **hold up** something such as someone's behaviour, you make it known to other people, so that they can criticize or praise it.*
>
> Examples:
>
> *She said the picture that had appeared in a Sunday newspaper had held her up to ridicule.*
>
> *He had always been held up as an example to the younger ones.*
>
> **[hold up](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hold%20up)** (M-W)
>
> 3 :  to call attention to :  single out.
>
> *His work was held up to ridicule*.